# Append a dataframe without duplicates when it is not immediately clear what a duplicate is

Tags: pandas

How can I append one dataframe to another, leaving out duplicates. The twist here is that it's not clear which are duplicates.

To be a duplicate the name must be the same and the game must be car_v1 in the first df and car_version_2 in the second df.

```
df1 name    age    game     col_d
0   Jane    7      car_v1   foo
1   Jamie   6      car_v1   bar
2   Kevin   9      car_v1   bar

df2 name    age    game            col_d
0   Dave    1      train game      foo
1   Kevin   9      plane game      bar
2   Jill    6      plane game      bar
3   Chris   3      car_version_2   foo
4   Kevin   9      car_version_2   bar
```

After they are merged/appended df2 should look like this:

```
df2 name    age    game            col_d
0   Dave    1      train game      foo
1   Kevin   9      plane game      bar
2   Jill    6      plane game      bar
3   Chris   3      car_version_2   foo
4   Kevin   9      car_version_2   bar
5   Jane    7      car_v1          foo
6   Jamie   6      car_v1          bar
```

Which leaves out Kevin's old game from the first df as he has the new version. Please note, df1 only has car_v1 in it.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved the problem, but it probably isn't very efficient. Perhaps someone can make a better alternative, but in the meantime, this is what I did:

```
#make a filtered DF with only the v2 completions in it
filteredDF = df2.loc[df2["game"] == "car_version_2"] 

#put the names of the filteredDF in a list
myList = filteredDF['name'].tolist()

#if a person already has a v2 game, then delete their v1 game as irrelevant
df1.ix[df1.name.isin(myList), "game"] = "delete"

#and delete it.
df1 = df1[df1.game != "delete"] 

#and then append it
df2 = df2.append(df1)
```